# Alter query according to user selection in sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite

> I have a sqlite database named StudentDB which has 3 columns Roll number, Name, Marks. Now I want to fetch only the columns that user selects in the IDE. User can select one column or two or all the three. How can I alter the query accordingly using Python?

I tried:

```
import sqlite3

sel={"Roll Number":12}

query = 'select * from StudentDB Where({seq})'.format(seq=','.join(['?']*len(sel))),[i for k,i in sel.items()]
con = sqlite3.connect(database)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query)

all_data = cur.fetchall()
all_data
```

I am getting:

```
operation parameter must be str
```

Comment: One important addition to both your code and the answers so far - be sure to positively assert that the keys of `sel` are expected column names, with something like `VALID_COLUMNS = {'Name', 'Roll number'}; assert sel.keys() <= VALID_COLUMNS`; otherwise you have a massive security hole

Comment: @sabik: it depends where the column names come from. It is absolutely required if the are read somewhere, but is useless is they are just hardcoded in the application. And the latter is a rather common use case...

Comment: They look to be coming from the user at least to some extent... and if it's a web app, the user could probably substitute anything

Answer (score 1):

You should control the text of the query. The where clause shall allways be in the form `WHERE colname=value [AND colname2=...]` or (better) `WHERE colname=? [AND ...]` if you want to build a parameterized query.

So you want:

```
query = 'select * from StudentDB Where ' + ' AND '.join('"{}"=?'.format(col)
                                                        for col in sel.keys())
...
cur.execute(query, tuple(sel.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `query` is now a tuple instead of `str` and that is why the error.

I assume you want to execute a query like below -

```
select * from StudentDB Where "Roll number"=?
```

Then you can change the sql query like this (assuming you want and and not or) -

```
query = "select * from StudentDB Where {seq}".format(seq=" and ".join('"{}"=?'.format(k) for k in sel.keys()))
```

and execute the query like -

```
cur.execute(query, tuple(sel.values()))
```

Please make sure in your code the provided `database` is defined and contains the database name and `studentDB` is indeed the table name and not database name.